# Issue with building iOS on AppseleratorStudio [ERROR]: Invalid "--device-id" value ""

Tags: ios, appcelerator-titanium

AppseleratorStudio (Titanium), build: 4.6.0.201605201934
MacBook Pro
iPad mini, OS 8.1.

Seen similar questions being asked, but not many answers were given and most of the questions were Android related. Willing to provide more info needed if necessary.

```
2016-08-22T08:48:24.385Z | DEBUG  | getTiDefaultPath /Users/at/Library/Application Support/Titanium
    2016-08-22T08:48:24.386Z | DEBUG  | active sdk install path /Users/at/Library/Application Support/Titanium
    2016-08-22T08:48:26.476Z | DEBUG  | to download {"modules":[{"oses":["linux","win32","osx"],"platforms":["iphone","android"],"required":true,"partner_id":"A0B129A418829127EC551EB8ADB0D1CC","partner_name":"Appcelerator","name":"Hyperloop","description":"Gain complete access to native APIs in your Titanium mobile applications.","id":"hyperloop","guid":"99a136cd-4e51-40da-bcdb-d514f5895fb5","version":"1.2.6","url":"http://appcelerator-modules.s3.amazonaws.com/hyperloop-1.2.6.zip","min_mobilesdk_version":"5.4.0"}],"components":[]}
    [ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value ""
    Available iOS Devices:
      814afcb29c793aea10b182b53f3f629b73ed1a39  iPad mini
      itunes                                    iTunes Sync
    For help, run: titanium.js help build
```

**Upd1.** Added device id in build command, here is the result:

```
[INFO]  Invoking xcodebuild
[ERROR]  BUILD FAILED 
[ERROR] The following build commands failed:
[ERROR]         CodeSign build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Anna-inzicht.app
[ERROR] (1 failure)
```

Also tried to clean project - no help.

**Upd2.** It works ok on emulator, fail is with real device only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the solution was easy - created new project, moved all files from `app` folder.
Build works now.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest fix is to go to "Debug Configurations..." and delete the config for your project. Studio will automatically rebuild it or maybe ask you for which Provisioning Profile you want to use.

While Goltsev Eugene works it's a bit much, as creating a new project makes you loose all history, analytics, push, etc. on appcelerator platform.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `--device-id 814afcb29c793aea10b182b53f3f629b73ed1a39` to your `titanium build` command.

Comment: Still fail to build and install. Pls. see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those still having this issue in 2019.

If you aren't able to locate your device in the device list, follow these simple steps.

Update NodeJS at https://nodejs.org/#download. Then rebuilding modules with by typing into the command-line: appc ti info -t ios.

You should see the following:

"You are attempting to run appc 7.1.0 which was compiled for node 8.9.1 but you are now running node v10.16.3
Rebuilding package modules ...
Package modules rebuilt!"

After that, my device popped up on my device list.

This took a while to figure out and I could not find this straight-forward solution anywhere.